# mov instruction in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, att, mov

From what I've read about `mov`, it copies the second argument into the first argument. Then, what does this do?

```
movl    8(%ebp),    %edx
```

It copies whatever is in edx to the first parameter of the function (since an offset of +8 from `ebp` is a parameter)?

I feel like what this really means is moving the first parameter into the `edx` register, but I read on Wikipedia that it is the other way around?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
movl 8(%ebp), %edx
```

is in "AT&T Syntax"; in this syntax, the source comes first and the destination second.  So yes, your belief is correct.  Most documentation uses the "Intel Syntax", which has the reverse ordering.  This is a source of considerable confusion for people new to x86 assembly.

In Intel Syntax, your instruction would be written:

```
mov edx, [ebp + 8]
```

Note the absence of `%` before the register names, and the use of square brackets instead of parentheses for the address, and the lack of an `l` suffix on the instruction.  These are dead giveaways to know which form of assembly you are looking at.

Comment: What is the reason for having 2 different dilects of assembly? As you noted, this can be a common source of confusion for newcomers since they use completely different conventions.

Comment: @Victor T.: Intel syntax is what Intel specified originally; AT&T syntax is an adaptation of a Bell Labs assembly syntax intended to be used on multiple platforms.

Comment: @Stephen: There is an error with Intel Synax. There must be `mov [ebp + 8], edx` :)

Comment: @Ilya: that would be a store, not a load.  The argument order in Intel syntax is reversed from AT&T syntax.

Comment: pardon me, the same `movl 8(%ebp), %edx`, op said 'it copies the second argument into the first argument', so it is `1 <- 2`, but here says 'in this syntax, the source comes first and the destination second', so it is `1 -> 2`, and then `So yes, your belief is correct`, totally confused now