# In the Assembly language, what does the 'l' in "movl" stands for?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I understand that `movb` is move byte, `movw` is move word, `movq` is move quad word. `movl` is move double word, but what does the `l` stands for?

Comment: Note that this depends on the architecture and the assembler you use.

Comment: [Assembly mov instruction without suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52594200/995714), [GNU AS: movl (%eax), %eax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6819957/995714), [mov instruction in x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890724/995714)

Comment: from GNU `as`: [*Instruction mnemonics are suffixed with one character modifiers which specify the size of operands. The letters ‘b’, ‘w’, ‘l’ and ‘q’ specify byte, word, long and quadruple word operands*](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html#Instruction-Naming). Also [Solaris assembler document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5477/817-5477.pdf), https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2627/2563, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax#Operation_Suffixes

Comment: This question is down voted and marked duplicate. But I want to defend myself a little bit: my question is about nomenclature, not syntax. I simply didn't know that the letter "l" in "movl" originally means "long". It is true that the answer to this question can be found in answers to other questions, but they are not easy to find. So I think the question is not a duplicate, even though the answer probably is.

Comment: When I learn I always want to know a bit about why things are called as they are called. I understand some people don't care about nomenclature. But I think questions about names are valid.

Answer (score 5):

According to *Computer System: A Programmer's Perspective*, page 215, it means "long" since

> 32-bit quantities are considered to be "long words"

But as @phuclv pointed out, it is better to refer to official documentations like the language standard.

Comment: you should read the documentation from the language standard or the assembler, not a book

Comment: @phuclv: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dVariations.html confirms that `l` stands for "long".  But doesn't go into any more detail than CS:APP.  GAS didn't invent this syntax, AT&T did, and GAS is just copying it.  So I think that's part of why the manual doesn't discuss the design in much detail.